# How to select insert from a table in SQL server with a where condition of a column time_stamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table audit_records with column time_stamp as datatime2 and I would like to insert all records which has time_stamp value greater than 2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 into a new table audit_records_current.

This because the table has over 75 million rows and I would like to delete this table after moving the rows newer than time_stamp 2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000.

Comment: Btw this is sql-sever 2014

Comment: Is that such hard to put a condition as `time_stamp > '2019-01-01'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new table called audit_records_current like so:

```
select *
into audit_records_current
from audit_records
where time_stamp > '2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000';
```

Then you can drop audit_records using `drop table audit_records;`

You have the choice of emptying out audit_records while still keeping the table. If you want to do that, just do `truncate table audit_records;`